# What differs a ring ideal from a congruence class in the integers?

Tags: ideals, congruence-relations

I know the following definitions:

> Congruence: $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ if $n \mid a-b$

> A subring $I$ of a ring $R$ is an ideal if whenever $r \in R$ and $a \in I$, then $ar \in I$ and $ra \in I$.
>
> Furthermore, if $a,b \in R$ and $a-b \in I$ then we can write $a \equiv b \pmod{I}$

Ideals seem to deal with congruences in some sense. But what actually differs a ring ideal from a congruence class in the integers?

Comment: Nothing much. $n\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, the notion of an ideal is *motivated* by modular arithmetic.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment 'thanks', but THANKS! Such a helpful explanation. Makes sense now.